# How to use react-scroll-parallax

Tags: reactjs, parallax

I `yarn add react-scroll-parallax`

to set up new features but there is an error:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ParallaxProvider, useParallaxController } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
import bannerimg from "../../assets/images/landingpage/banner-img.png";
import Image from "next/image";

function Rakieta() {
    const parallaxController = useParallaxController();

    const handleLoad = () => parallaxController.update();
    return (

<ParallaxProvider>
<Image  onLoad={handleLoad} src={bannerimg} alt="hero banner" className="my-thing" />

</ParallaxProvider>

  )
}

export default Rakieta
```

it provide a following error:
Could not find `react-scroll-parallax` context value. Please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<ParallaxProvider>`

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `Rakieta` component by `<ParallaxProvider>` in parent component.

e.g.

```
<ParallaxProvider>
   <Parent>
       <Rakieta />
   </Parent>
</ParallaxProvider>
```

But you wrap it inside `Rakieta` where `useParallaxController` is used.